# unknown timezone 'localtime'

Tags: r, azure, timezone

I think I have done everything right, but why am I getting this:

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2015-11-09 18:51:17 UTC"
Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'localtime'
2: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'localtime'
>
```

Operating system is Windows Server 2012 (an Azure VM actually). I have set my timezone to be UTC with the `TZ` environment variable:

[image]

The `Sys.timezone` apparently sees it:

```
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "UTC"
>
```

And it is even listed in my `OlsonNames()`:

[image]

I get tons of these error messages in my markdown, and it is driving me crazy. Ominously, I noticed the other SO links related to this frequently are unresolved.

**Update** - per request I am adding `sessionInfo()` output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.2.6 tools_3.2.2     yaml_2.1.13     rmarkdown_0.8.1
[5] digest_0.6.8   
>
```

and a traceback:

```
> options(warn=2)
> Sys.time()
Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : 
  (converted from warning) unknown timezone 'localtime'
> traceback()
13: doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
12: withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
11: withRestarts({
        .Internal(.signalCondition(simpleWarning(msg, call), msg, 
            call))
        .Internal(.dfltWarn(msg, call))
    }, muffleWarning = function() NULL)
10: .signalSimpleWarning("unknown timezone 'localtime'", quote(as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, 
        tz)))
9: as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz)
8: as.POSIXlt(x, tz)
7: format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz), format, usetz, ...)
6: structure(format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz), format, usetz, ...), 
       names = names(x))
5: format.POSIXct(x, usetz = TRUE)
4: format(x, usetz = TRUE)
3: print(format(x, usetz = TRUE), ...)
2: print.POSIXct(x)
1: function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print")(x)
>
```

**Update** more info:
[image]

Comment: Please edit the output from: 1) `sessionInfo()`, and 2) `options(warn=2); Sys.time(); traceback()` into your question.

Comment: And presumably the Windows OS is also set to UTC? As in, via the control panel or `tzutil.exe /g`

Comment: Yep. Added another screenshot. The machine however is in Texas somewhere I believe.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. Servers, esp. cloud, should always be on UTC anyway.  And I think R provides its own Olson time zone data.  But thanks for checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to be a known bug in R 3.2.2 and fixed in 3.2.3, per [this issue report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16503).